# Looping over a directory of large local excel files from a remote server, causes repeated access to same files

Tags: python, excel, jupyter

I am using a vendor supplied jupyter environment hosted over a remote server, the project files are stored locally.

I have a bunch of excel files I read data from and use vendor api to get other fields.

I am running into an issue where if I use os.listdir() to loop, I keep accessing the same files. I feel that the vendor application takes a snapshot of my project directory periodically to sync and if in the meantime I am in midst of accessing data from a large excel file, the file iterator gets reset to the new snapshot and I end up reading the same files over and over.

```py
for file in os.listdir(path):

    print(file)

    full_file_name=os.path.join(path,file)

    try:

        with pd.ExcelFile(full_file_name) as file_read:

            print(file_read)

            ## Code to read data from different tabs
```

```
Output:

Portfolio positions 3.xlsx
Portfolio positions 3.xlsx
<pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile object at 0x000001C8CB10BCF8>
Portfolio positions 3.xlsx
<pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile object at 0x000001C8CB10BCF8>
Portfolio positions 4.xlsx
Portfolio positions 3.xlsx
<pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile object at 0x000001C8CB10BCF8>
Portfolio positions 4.xlsx
<pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile object at 0x000001C8CAF12908>
Portfolio positions 3.xlsx
<pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile object at 0x000001C8CB10BCF8>
Portfolio positions 4.xlsx
<pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile object at 0x000001C8CAF12908>
Portfolio positions 5.xlsx
Portfolio positions 3.xlsx
<pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile object at 0x000001C8CB10BCF8>
...
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why you're experiencing this problem, but an easy solution would be to read files into a list first and create a set to only iterate over unique file names.

```
files = set(os.listdir(path))
for filename in files:
    print(filename)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I have already tried that, but has similar output. It just seems that it sees a new instance of os.listdir whenever it syncs and therefore keep reading the same files.

Answer (score 0):

> in the meantime I am in midst of accessing data from a large excel file, the file iterator gets reset to the new snapshot and I end up reading the same files over and over.

I don't think this is what's happening to you, my understanding of Python is that os.listdir() is getting called once. That said, I can't explain the behavior you're seeing, and so I recommend guarding against it anyway.

Try assembling the files into a list and then processing them.

```py
full_file_names = []
for _file in os.listdir(path):
    print(_file)
    full_file_names.append(os.path.join(path, _file))

for full_file in full_file_names:
    try:
        ...
```

Also, try not to use `file` as it masks a built-in.

Comment: thanks, I tried it and had the same issue. I just feel calling os.listdir remotely on local directory and the syncing of the remote and local directory maybe out of whack.

Comment: You should try printing out ```full_file_names``` after you have collected it and verify that it's the same as what you believe should be in the folder. Otherwise, if it's iterating over the same files repeatedly, then you must have a bigger loop where you're calling all of this repeatedly.

Comment: `code`
full_file_names = []
for _file in os.listdir(path):
    print(_file)
    full_file_names.append(os.path.join(path, _file))
    
print(len(full_file_names))
Portfolio positions 3.xlsx
Portfolio positions 4.xlsx
Portfolio positions 5.xlsx
Portfolio positions 6.xlsm
Portfolio positions 7.xlsm
Portfolio positions 8.xlsm
6